Debug SQL Server on Ubuntu 22 from Visual Studio 2022 fails
I run MSSQL on a Ubuntu 22 machine in the same network. I can connect from SSMS to the database and I can execute queries from VS 2022 on that database. So I guess it is no user or firewall issue. Only if I try to debug some stored procedure (which I regularly do on my Windows localhost) I get this

and this

Has anybody an answer to that?
Thanks.
BTW: I searched the web but found no appropriate answer.
PS: I also tried this from an old SSMS 17.9 with integrated debugger and the "Debug" butto is disabled. Maybe the linux server does not allow debugging?

I think debugger uses RPC and COM stuff to communicate with the server which pretty sure doesn't run on linux

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.

Unless the SQL Server for Linux instance is Kerberos authenticated you might have some difficulties... SQL Debugging: Unable to start T-SQL Debugging. Could not attach to SQL Server process Connecting the Transact-SQL editor to the server with a login having the sysadmin fixed server role is not sufficient; the Windows login of the Visual Studio user must also be a member of the sysadmin fixed server role on that instance of SQL Server.

See also Requirements for starting the debugger.

Can you explain exactly what you're going to get from explicit debugging that you can't get from normal debugging of T-SQL (ex. PRINT)? See this video, for example.

Are you using SQL Server Data Tools in Visual Studio to debug your stored procedure?
If not, please try to use SSDT to debug stored procedures to see if the issue persists.
Please check the following steps:
1.Connecting to the SQL Server Instance
Please connect to the SQL Server instance running on Ubuntu 22 with SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS).
2 Debugging SQL Queries in Visual Studio 2022
(1) Open Visual Studio 2022 and create a Database project.
(2) In Solution Explorer, right-click the project and select Add, then Stored Procedure and click Add.
(3) Set breakpoints in the SQL query as needed.
(4) Start the debugger by clicking the "Start" button in the toolbar
Execute the SQL query in the debugger.
The debugger will stop at the breakpoints, allowing you to inspect the state of the query and make any necessary changes.
For more information, please refer to doc:How to Debug Stored Procedures
Hope it can help you.
